# Wait for Docker container to become running using Python SDK

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

Using the `docker` module for Python, you can start a detached container like this:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(some_image, detach=True)
```

I need to wait for this container to be `running` (ie `container.status == 'running'`). If you check the status immediately after creating the container, it will report this, meaning that it is not yet ready:

```py
>>> container.status
"created"
```

The API does provide a `wait()` method, but this only waits for termination statuses like `exit` and `removed`: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.wait.

How can I wait until my container is `running` using `docker` for Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a while loop with a timeout

```py
import docker
from time import sleep 

client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.run(some_image, detach=True)

timeout = 120
stop_time = 3
elapsed_time = 0
while container.status != 'running' and elapsed_time < timeout:
    sleep(stop_time)
    elapsed_time += stop_time
    continue
```

Comment: In my experience, `container.status` does not get updated from `'created'` to `'running'` when the container starts running. You should use `docker.containers.get(container.id)` to get the latest status.

Comment: @bjschoenfeld, to update container status you can also use `container.reload()` instead of `docker.containers.get(container.id)`.